# linux bash script "xdotool windowactivate $variable" returning error

Tags: linux, bash, x11, xdotool

```
echo $Win_ret
    #returns 98566150

#xdotool windowactivate 98566150
    #functions

xdotool windowactivate $Win_ret
    #does not function
```

I assume that this is a syntax error, or variable type. I don't have much experience with bash.

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
case $1 in
   "play")
       key="ctrl+p"
       ;;
   "next")
       key='ctrl+n'
       ;;
   "prev")
       key='ctrl+b'
       ;;
   "rand")
        key='ctrl+shift+l'
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Usage: $0 play|next|prev|rand"
       exit 1
        ;;
esac

declare -i Win_ret=&(xdotool getactivewindow)

xdotool search --name "MediaMonkey" windowactivate #--sync
sleep 0.1
xdotool key $key
sleep 0.1

echo $Win_ret
    #returns 98566150

#xdotool windowactivate 98566150
    #functions

xdotool windowactivate $Win_ret
    #does not function

exit 0
```

I am expecting the line:

```
xdotool windowactivate $Win_ret
```

to return me to the window 98566150 as this does:

```
xdotool windowactivate 98566150
```

Instead it pops this error when run in terminal:

```
There are no windows in the stack
Invalid window '%1'
Usage: windowactivate [options] [window=%1]
--sync    - only exit once the window is active (is visible + active)
If no window is given, %1 is used. See WINDOW STACK in xdotool(
```

I have tried with and without declaring Win_ret as an integer.

Placing " around $Win_ret gives a different error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

xdotool uses binary references to windows.

Comment: `Win_ret=&(xdotool getactivewindow)` should be `Win_ret=$(xdotool getactivewindow)`.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem code.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can identify many common problems with shell code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Try Using `Win_ret=$(xdotool getactivewindow)` in place of `declare -i Win_ret=&(xdotool getactivewindow)` should work.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you pjh and mandy8055. The correction causes it to function. I shall have a good look at Shellcheck also.

Comment: @pjh, will you put that in an answer, so the question can be closed?

Comment: @ghoti it's a typo. Typo-based questions should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `&` with `$` on line `declare -i Win_ret=&(xdotool getactivewindow)` to get your script working. `&` operator in bash is primairly used to run a command in the background, not to get the output of a command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 
case $1 in
   "play")
       key="ctrl+p"
       ;;
   "next")
       key='ctrl+n'
       ;;
   "prev")
       key='ctrl+b'
       ;;
   "rand")
        key='ctrl+shift+l'
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Usage: $0 play|next|prev|rand"
       exit 1
        ;;
esac

declare -i Win_ret=$(xdotool getactivewindow) # this line

xdotool search --name "MediaMonkey" windowactivate #--sync
sleep 0.1
xdotool key $key
sleep 0.1

echo $Win_ret

xdotool windowactivate $Win_ret

exit 0
echo $Win_ret

xdotool windowactivate $Win_ret
```

Thanks to **@pjh** for suggesting a wonderful webapp **[shellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)** which was new for me as well to test your script for these types of minor problems and solution suggestion. You can also make use of the same to identify this problem.

Comment: This is a nice answer (other than the erroneous backslash in `case \$1`) but please don't answer questions which are just simple typo errors. They are virtually never going to be useful for future visitors, and should simply be closed as noise. (Do leave a comment if you see what's wrong, though.) Answers complicate the automatic curation and upvoted answers make it impossible to delete this question. Perhaps see also [help.](/help/roomba)

Comment: @tripleee Yes thanks` \$1` will be treated as a literal string, not as a variable. It got introduced as a typo. I'll update it. And yes your point makes sense, Actually, I am relatively new to answering questions on SO. If you want I can delete my answer. And going forward I'll make a note of it.

Comment: The problem is we cannot vote to delete as long as this is upvoted. The question can be delete-voted once it's old enough, but again, this complicates the curation process. _You_ can delete this answer, but that's kind of unattractive at this point in the process, too. What I'm trying to say is, going forward, please abstain from answering typo questions. Once you earn enough rep, you will be able to vote to close them; until then, just move along (or flag if you like).

Comment: (There's a second stray backslash in the usage message.)

Comment: It isn't a typo, I wasn't aware of the grammar for assigning a variable using xdotool.

Comment: The grammar is very basic and not at all specific to `xdotool`. Then this is simply a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command